# Position child divs fit within a parent in vertical order

Tags: css

I'm trying to have child divs fit within a parent in vertical order.  If it goes beyond the parent div's area, then it should begin in a new column to the right.

There is also a banner are at the top that takes the entire length of the parent div.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
}

#mainArea {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #777;
}

#mainBanner {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  float: bottom;
}

div[id^="box_"] {
  position: relative;
  width: 105px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #333;
  float: bottom;
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainArea">
  <div id="mainBanner">
  </div>
  <div id="box_1"></div>
  <div id="box_2"></div>
  <div id="box_3"></div>
  <div id="box_4"></div>
  <div id="box_5"></div>
  <div id="box_6"></div>
  <div id="box_7"></div>
  <div id="box_8"></div>
  <div id="box_9"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s70o7ngg/).

Currently the 9th box has extended past the bottom of the parent div. Is there a way to make it start a new column to the right of the first column?

Comment: FYI there is no `float: bottom`. Left and right are the only valid float values.

Comment: Oh, good to know.  In that case would there be no way to achieve what I need to achieve in the original question?  Or would I have to make another separate div for each column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Flexible Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) to do it, here's an example:

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Box 1</div>
    <div>Box 2</div>
    <div>Box 3</div>
    <div>Box 4</div>
    <div>Box 5</div>
    <div>Box 6</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column wrap;
   max-height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

.container div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #F00;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0F0;
}
```

You can test it it here if you want: https://jsfiddle.net/pg0y2d39/1/